# Why does my OnTriggerStay method throw a NullPointerException when I access the collider's attachedRigidbody?

Tags: unity, physics, rigidbody

I set the trigger

```
 void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{

    other.attachedRigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up * 100, ForceMode.Impulse);


}
```

But when player walks on, I got console warning

```
    NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

I have set Rigidbody on the player.

How to make player be affected by trigger ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that `OnTriggerStay` triggers when *any* game object with a collider (on one of the [physics layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) which collide with that of this object) collides with the object. You might be registering a collision with something other than the player. So you should check if the object you are colliding with is actually the player. A good way to do this is to set the tag of your player object to "Player" and then check for that tag in the collision method:

```
void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        other.attachedRigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up * 100, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}
```

When you still get that error instead of the expected results, then the most likely explanation is that you think you added a rigidbody to your player, but you actually didn't. In that case please edit the question with some screenshots which show how your player object looks in the inspector.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But now the problem is that Main camera which is child of the Player does not get affected by AddForce. So, Player still doesn't move up.

Comment: @eon When the camera is a child of the player, then it should move when the player moves. If you added a rigidbody to your camera, you should remove it. There is generally no reason to add a rigidbody to an object which is not supposed to have a physical presence in the game.

Comment: I removed it it now. Player still doesn't move.

Comment: @eon this is not a problem we can diagnose & troubleshoot with the information you've given us so far. Try asking a separate question, including all the details we'd need to reproduce your scene and player control ourselves, so we can directly observe the problem.

Comment: Ah, I understand now what is the problem. I will make seperate question.